# How do we reset the blog_id count in a WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I've just cloned all my subsites (40) from one Multisite to another of my Multisite installations. I want to use this opportunity to clean-up/reset the blog counter in my old MU to start at 2 again. Currently the blog counter is at 64 even though i only had 40 subsites. I know its like a primary-key in the db and auto increments with every new subsite created. With all my deletions and tinkerings over the months its left lots of gaps in the indexing numbers. I've found the column **'blog_count' in the wp_sitemeta** Db table in MySQL and it currently stands at 40, correctly but i can't believe its the only place that the count exists and don't want to risk mucking about with it. Could it be safely altered??

Comment: Can you tell us why is this bothering you ? is there a functional problem ?  it should have absolutely no effect of the real functioning of the sites .. it is just like the `post_id` ( or GUID ) count in posts that is not exactly linear where also a media upload is counted, and also post that have been deleted ..  it is totally transparent procedure to both admin and users

Comment: I'm aware of all of your points - and i know the importance of the id indexing, very much like a primary-key on your db. Its purely a chance to reclaim all those subsite ids which have left the gaps that bug me - its a OCD thing with me i think - nothing technical. If there's any time to do it it would be now. Once i start adding new subsites to the original multisite indexes will begin at 65; Maddness!!! I can well understand the absolute carnage as a result of tampering with the blog_count manually - just wondered if it was as easy as resetting it to #2 ...

Comment: Well, no one like me can understand tha `ocd` issue. there is a way to do it - i will post an answer asap when i have some time ...

Comment: Hey would you believe i figured it out! - the blog_count isn't really instrumental in the indexing; it simply denotes the true number of blogs present in the installation IE if you have 50 blogs and delete 35, blog_count will indicate 15 remaining; its not the next or current auto-increment value. The key to doing it is to change the actual auto-increment value MySQL > TableName > Operations - easy. so when you've deleted all subsites and your left with your primary site; set next auto-increment to 2 ...done

Answer (score 2):

The next sub-site of the multisite is defined by the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of the `wp_blogs` DB table. It defines the next `blog_id` primary key. We can find `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the Operations tab of the table in the phpMyAdmin. But we can't change it to less number than used in the table.

But we can export the `wp_blogs` table, change it with Notepad++, then delete the table and import the changed table. Actually, I guess we can do it with the whole DB and replace any `wp_{old_index}_` to `wp_{new_index}_`.

The example.
Let's imagine we have sub-sites from index 7 and more. These are steps for changing `wp_7_{tables}` to `wp_2_{tables}` (it's the first after the root site):

1. Make a full backup.:)
2. Remove all unnecessary sites (for example
   wp_8_, etc.). Remove tables with old prefixes too.
3. Use the Search tab and change all DB fields with `wp_7_{filedname}` to
   `wp_2_{filedname}`. Because there are some important site's metas with field starting with `wp_{n}_{fieldname}`.
4. On the Operation tab rename all DB tables with `wp_7_{tablename}`
   to `wp_2_{tablename}`.
5. Change the `wp_blogs` table increment to 3 (it's next after 2): export the table in the phpMyAdmin, edit it, delete the original, and import the changed table back. The table is small it will easy.
6. Done. Add the next site with index 3.